# Convert string to JSON object and send it as response

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am constructing a string like the following:

```
List<string> itemList = new List<string>();

foreach (i in items)
{
 itemList.Add("{ type: " + i.DocumentType + " ,id: " + i.ID + " ,name: " + i.name + " }" );
}
```

I want to convert the itemList to a JSON object and return it as response in my controller.

Please help.

Comment: What framework are you using? ASP.NET Web API? ASP.NET MVC? ASP.NET Core MVC?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using ASP.Net MVC

Comment: I am also using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq; and Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: why are you constructing List<string> instead of creating a list of objects?

Comment: can't you just simply serialize items? If not why?

Comment: ssilas777, could you please guide me to create a list of objects .

Comment: @Ralf how can I serialize items please

Comment: Did you read the Newtonsoft documentation? It shows lots of examples. And there are many many other examples online using that library, including on this site. It should not be hard to search for. Do you really need to ask people to repeat it again? Do some basic research, then ask us if you have a problem with the code you're trying. Or check the answers below, which already show examples for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ASP.Net MVC you could use Linq to get your List in your desired style and then convert to Json using Json(). ie:

```
public JsonResult GetMyItems()
{
   var myItems = items.Select(i => new { 
                    type = i.DocumentType,
                    id = i.ID,
                    name = i.name
                 });

   return Json(myItems, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Serializing and Deserializing JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)

```
public class Data {
 public Data(string type, long id, string name) {
  Type = type;
  Id = id;
  Name = name
 }
 public string Type { get; set; }
 public long Id { get; set; }
 public string Name {get; set;
}

var itemList = items.Select(i => Data(i.DocumentType , i.ID, i.name).ToList();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(itemList);
```

Comment: Note that this is not what OP wants to do even if they try to ask for it.